# Where can I find all the properties associated with spark structured streaming?

Tags: scala, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I wonder if there is a listing somewhere of all the properties associated with spark structured streaming ?

For instance in the doc we can find:

```
spark.sql.streaming.schemaInference

spark.sql.streaming.metricsEnabled
```

When I do `spark.sql("SET -v").show(numRows = 200, truncate = false)`
as recommended in the documentation for configuration over spark sql the only thing that i see are:

```
spark.sql.streaming.numRecentProgressUpdates
spark.sql.streaming.metricsEnabled 
spark.sql.streaming.checkpointLocation
```

However I don't see `***spark.sql.streaming.schemaInference***`

Hence my question what is the consistence way to see all the properties that can be used to set spark structured streaming behavior. Are Spark streaming properties part of all that apply to Spark structured streaming behavior ? I am interested in controlling the rate per mini-batch (i.e. mini dataFrame aka number of of ROWS per processing)

Answer (score 1):

I tried to find all of configurations in the official Spark website, but I've failed.
So here is the original code about configuration of [Spark 2.4.0](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.0/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/internal/SQLConf.scala).
You can find all of structured streaming configurations as searching `spark.sql.streaming`.

Comment: I've checked one more time. You can still find all configurations by searching `spark.sql.streaming` but I think you can use only except with `.internal()` code.